# How to retrieve values from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is stockstore and another expenses and I want calculate profit and loss search between two date. So I want to calculate total expenses amount when give value in textfield.

**stockstore Table**

```
          id| date       | ItemName | Price
          1   09/04/2015   Apple       40
          2   10/04/2015   Banana      30
          3   12/04/2015   Salt        10
```

**Expenses Table**

```
         id | Date       |Expenses Type| Amount
          1   14/04/2015   Travel      |100
          2   17/04/2015   Decoration   200
```

I want when search by date between two date Between `09/04/2015` AND `17/04/2015` it shoud be display like that

```
        id| date       | ItemName | Price
          1   09/04/2015   Apple       40
          2   10/04/2015   Banana      30
          3   12/04/2015   Salt        10 
          1   14/04/2015   Travel      100
          2   17/04/2015   Decoration  200
```

Comment: you did any try? or just want us to work for you?

Comment: To answer the question as-per the title - perform multiple queries in a single statement, separating the queries with a semicolon(;)..

Comment: yes i have tried like that

Comment: select id , date,itemname,price from stockstore  union select id ,date,expensestype, amount from expenses;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    stockstore.id,
    stockstore.date,
    stockstore.ItemName,
    stockstore.Price
FROM
    stockstore
WHERE
    stockstore.date BETWEEN '09/04/2015' AND '17/04/2015'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Expenses.id,
    Expenses.date,
    Expenses.`Expenses Type`,
    Expenses.Price
FROM
    Expenses
WHERE
    Expenses.date BETWEEN '09/04/2015' AND '17/04/2015'
```

Comment: how to add calendar in JTextField

Comment: @DeepakSingh : That is a separate question. The question that you have asked is answered. If you have more questions or problem. Then create a new question and mark this question as answered

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way of doing it.

```
stockstore = SELECT Price FROM stockstore WHERE date BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
Expenses = SELECT Amount FROM Expenses WHERE Date BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;

foreach(stockstores as stockstore)
    //add up stockstore
foreach(Expenses as Expense)
    //add up Expense

profit = stockstore - Expense
```